# proper way of copying files to destination with gulp

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, gulp

I'm toying around with ASP.NET 5 and am using gulp. I added angularjs and angular-route to my package.json file which stored the files at Dependencies->NPM. I added this to my gulpfile.js thinking that it would copy over the the correct JS files. It did copy over the files, however, it also crashed the project. I had to manually go into the lib folder and remove everything that gulp added. What's the proper way to copy files from the NPM folder a destination folder. I'd like to be able to just run the task from Task Runner.

I'm assuming this is incorrect: (which is what I ran)

```
gulp.task("copyJs", function () {
    return gulp.src('./node_modules/**/*.js')        
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/lib/'))  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it but one of the good simple ways I found was this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ControlHowYourBowerPackagesAreInstalledWithAGulpfileInASPNET5.aspx

Which do an update to the bowerrc file and everything after this update makes more sense.

> UPDATE YOUR .BOWERRC AND PROJECT.JSON
>
> In the root of your project is a .bowerrc file. It looks like this:

```
> {   "directory": "wwwroot/lib" } Change it to something like this, and
> delete your actual wwwroot/lib folder.
> 
> {   "directory": "bower_components" } EXCLUDE YOUR SOURCE BOWER FOLDER
> FROM YOUR PROJECT.JSON
```

> You'll also want to go into your project.json file for ASP.NET 5 and
>   make sure that your source bower_components folder is excluded from
>   the project and any packing and publishing process.

```
> "exclude": [
>     "wwwroot",
>     "node_modules",
>     "bower_components"   ],
```

> UPDATE YOUR GULPFILE.JS
>
> In your gulpfile, make sure that path is present in paths. There are
>   totally other ways to do this, including having gulp install bower and
>   figure out the path. It's up to you how sophisticated you want your
>   gulpfile to get as long as the result is that production ready .js
>   ends up in your wwwroot ready to be served to the customer. Also
>   include a lib or destination for where your resulting JavaScript gets
>   copied. Could be scripts, could be js, could be lib as in my case.
>
> var paths = {
>       webroot: "./" + project.webroot + "/",
>       bower: "./bower_components/",
>       lib: "./" + project.webroot + "/lib/" }; ADD A COPY TASK TO YOUR GULPFILE
>
> Now open your Gulpfile and note all the tasks. You're going to add a
>   copy task to copy in just the files you want for deployment with your
>   web app.
>
> Here is an example copy task:

```
> gulp.task("copy", ["clean"], function () {
>     var bower = {
>         "bootstrap": "bootstrap/dist/**/*.{js,map,css,ttf,svg,woff,eot}",
>         "bootstrap-touch-carousel": "bootstrap-touch-carousel/dist/**/*.{js,css}",
>         "hammer.js": "hammer.js/hammer*.{js,map}",
>         "jquery": "jquery/jquery*.{js,map}",
>         "jquery-validation": "jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js",
>         "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"
>     }
>  
>     for (var destinationDir in bower) {
>         gulp.src(paths.bower + bower[destinationDir])
>           .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.lib + destinationDir));
>     } });
```

> Do note this is a very simple and very explicit copy tasks. Others
>   might just copy more or less, or even use a globbing wildcard.
>   It's up to you. The point is, if you don't like a behavior in ASP.NET
>   5 or in the general build flow of your web application you have more
>   power than ever before.
>
> Right click the Bower node in the Solution Explorer and "Restore
>   Packages." You can also do this in the command line or just let it
>   happen at build time.
>
> Looking in this simplified screenshot, you can see the bower
>   dependencies that come down into the ~/bower_components folder. Just
>   the parts I want are moved into the ~/wwwroot/lib/** folder when the
>   gulpfile runs the copy task.

Answer (score 3):

*I think the trailing `'/'` in `gulp.dest('./wwwroot/lib/')` might be the cause of the problem, try `gulp.dest('./wwwroot/lib')` instead.

This is the gulp workflow I use for Angular 2 with Asp.Net 5.

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    merge = require("merge-stream"),
    rimraf = require("rimraf");

var paths = {
    webroot: "./wwwroot/",
    node_modules: "./node_modules/"
};

paths.libDest = paths.webroot + "lib/";

gulp.task("clean:libs", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.libDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("copy:libs", ["clean:libs"], function () {
    var angular2 = gulp.src(paths.node_modules + "angular2/bundles/**/*.js")
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.libDest + "angular2"));

    var es6_shim = gulp.src([
            paths.node_modules + "es6-shim/*.js",
            "!**/Gruntfile.js"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.libDest + "es6-shim"));

    var systemjs = gulp.src(paths.node_modules + "systemjs/dist/*.js")
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.libDest + "systemjs"));

    var rxjs = gulp.src(paths.node_modules + "rxjs/bundles/**/*.js")
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.libDest + "rxjs"));

    return merge(angular2, es6_shim, systemjs, rxjs);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage very complex monorepos, I don't like hardcoded file paths and prefer to mirror my source code for transparency. I explored a LOT of solutions for doing a lot of files at once and find them all opaque and bloated. I recommend a factory that ultimately does this with source-like file module references:

```js
gulp.parallel(
  () =>
    gulp
      .src(require.resolve('@bootstrap/core/dist/bootstrap.all.min.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(DIST)),
  () =>
    gulp
      .src(require.resolve('foobar/dist/foobar.all.min.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(DIST))
```

You can make them named functions for visibility as well.